# Raspberry Pi 3 bare metal: unexpected behaviour from arrays and switch statements

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I currently have a simple program that sets up a framebuffer that can be written to.

I am encountering behaviour where values stored i arrays, once retrieved, come back as seemingly random values, with no relation to the originals.
I have also noticed some similarly strange and.unexpected behaviour from switch statements - I suspect this has something to do with how both arrays and switch statements are statically allocated in memory.

As an example, here I have some code that should draw a hardcoded number, followed by 7 other hardcoded numbers that have been stored in an array:

```
unsigned int cols[7] = { 0xFFFF0000, 0xFFFF7F00, 0xFFFFFF00, 0xFF00FF00, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF4B0082, 0xFF9400D3 };
drawNum(&display, 0x1234ABCD);
for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
  drawNum(&display, cols[i]);
```

The first `drawNum()` call with the hardcoded value works fine, but all of the calls with array accesses give seemingly random results.

Assigning the array values at runtime doesn't have this problem, like so:

```
unsigned int cols[7];
cols[0] = 0xFFFF0000;
cols[1] = 0xFFFF7F00;
cols[2] = 0xFFFFFF00;
cols[3] = 0xFF00FF00;
cols[4] = 0xFF0000FF;
cols[5] = 0xFF4B0082;
cols[6] = 0xFF9400D3;
drawNum(&display, 0x1234ABCD);
drawNum(&display, (int)cols);
for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
  drawNum(&display, cols[i]);
```

I've also experienced similarly unpredictable behaviour when returning values from `switch` statements.

I cannot say for sure, but this leads me to believe that this is a problem with the compiler or linker being used - I am using `arm-none-eabi`.

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you show, it's somewhere in the code you *don't* show. You probably have *undefined behavior* somewhere, maybe going out of bounds of memory somewhere (perhaps in the `drawNum` function?

Comment: Probaly wrong linker script, wrong startup code or the wrong compiler

Comment: This is where we explain that in order to do more than make guesses, we need a [mre] that demonstrates the (mis)behavior you're asking about.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, the difficulty with that is how much boilerplate code is needed to get any actual output from the pi, since this is bare metal

Comment: @P__J__ any idea what should be used here? We're currently using `arm-none-eabi-gcc`.

Comment: @NatKarmios, at least a minimal, complete, function(s) and any relevant file-scope object definitions with which you can reproduce the issue would be appropriate.  The definition of `drawNum()` might not be needed (though we do want its prototype), if you can confirm that the example function you do present does the expected thing when it passes an integer literal to `drawNum()`, but not when it passes an array element that holds the same value (where the example establishes a basis for that array element's value).

Comment: looks like a linker script problem, what happens if you add const to the array declaration, does it then work?

Comment: As already said, without the code of `drawNum()` we can only try to guess, so here is my guess: try to add `volatile`, or `const`, or `const volatile` to your definition of `cols` and see if you get a better behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but you may want to try a different value in your array where the highest bit is 0 instead of 1 like in your hardcoded example.

```
unsigned int cols[7] = { 0x7FFF0000, 0x7FFF7F00, 0x7FFFFF00, 0x7F00FF00, 0x7F0000FF, 0x7F4B0082, 0x7F9400D3 };
```

This is assuming that drawNum takes an int instead of an unsigned int. You might just have a conversion problem. Without seeing what drawNum does it's hard to say.

Comment: Tried this, sorry. We believe it's a problem with the linker rather than the actual values stored; we have the same problem with strings and other arrays.

Answer (score 0):

And here my shot in the dark. You have a memory overwrite anywhere and this kills `cols[]`. If you move the variable from global scope to local scope the outcome varies. Add some 'detector' code:

```
volatile unsigned int cols[7] = { 0xFFFF0000, 0xFFFF7F00, 0xFFFFFF00, 0xFF00FF00, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF4B0082, 0xFF9400D3 };
drawNum(&display, 0x1234ABCD);

//test code
drawNum(&display, cols[0]==0xFFFF0000);    
drawNum(&display, cols[1]==0xFFFF7F00);

for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
  drawNum(&display, cols[i]);      

//test code
drawNum(&display, cols[0]==0xFFFF0000);    
drawNum(&display, cols[1]==0xFFFF7F00);
```

I added the volatile keyword to avoid optimizations by the compiler. It shouldn't mask away the observed wrong output.